# Method not being passed between classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

So this is the code i have:

ViewA.h:

```
#import "ViewB.h"
#import "ViewC.h"

@interface ViewA : UIViewController {

    ViewB *viewB;
    ViewC *viewC;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) ViewB *viewB;

@end
```

ViewA.m:

```
@synthesize viewB;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
viewB = [[ViewB alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 328)];
    [self.view addSubview:viewB];

   viewC = [[ViewC alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 332, 320, 84)];
    [self.view addSubview:viewC];

    }
```

ViewB.h:

```
-(void)methodToPass;
```

ViewB.m:

```
-(void)methodToPass {

NSLog(@"Passed.");
}
```

ViewC.h:

```
#import "ViewB.h"

@interface ViewC : UIScrollView {

ViewB *viewB;

}

-(void)methodWhichDoesGetPassed;
```

ViewC.m:

```
#import "ViewA.h"

@implementation ViewC

ViewA *viewA;

-(void)methodWhichDoesGetPassed {
NSLog(@"Test here");
[viewA.viewB methodToPass];

}
```

So the key bit of that is that i tried to pass the method to viewB, from viewC, through viewA in that last part. When i run the app, i get the "Test here" but not the "Passed", so it doesn't pass this through.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is viewB non NIL when calling "methodToPass"? - e.g. `NSLog("Test here - calling on instance %@", viewA.viewB);`

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have created an instance of viewA in your ViewC class.

Comment: Adding in  `NSLog(@"test: %@", viewA.viewB);` does return null actually. So i'm guessing that's where my problem lies.

Comment: Also you are creating an instance variable of type ViewB, but not using it to call `methodToPass`, why not just call [viewB methodToPass]?

Comment: Just tried that. Still returns null and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since `viewC` is a subview of `viewA`, you should send messages to the `superview`.</strike>

change it to

```
ViewA *view = (ViewA *)self.superview;

[view.viewB methodToPass];
```

**EDIT**

You can even check if the superview is an instance of `ViewA` before casting.

```
if ( [self.superview isMemberOfClass:[ViewA class]] ) {
    ViewA *view = (ViewA *)self.superview;
    [view.viewB methodToPass];
}
```

**EDIT2**

Rather than having to message up to `viewA` and down to `viewB` again, wouldn't it be better to pass `viewB` to `viewC` on instantiation. Suggesting some changes based on that.

ViewA.m:

```
@synthesize viewB;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    viewB = [[ViewB alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 328)];
    [self.view addSubview:viewB];

    viewC = [[ViewC alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 332, 320, 84)];
    viewC.viewB = viewB;
    [self.view addSubview:viewC];

}
```

ViewC.h:

```
#import "ViewB.h"

@interface ViewC : UIScrollView {
    ViewB *viewB;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewB *viewB;

-(void)methodWhichDoesGetPassed;
...
@end
```

ViewC.m:

```
@implementation ViewC

@synthesize viewB;

-(void)methodWhichDoesGetPassed {
    NSLog(@"Test here");
    [viewB methodToPass];

}
```

**Original Answer**

Comment: Then it gives me an error of "Request for member 'viewB' in something not a structure or a union. Probably because the superview for this view could be any view, not specifically viewA?

Comment: You need to `import "ViewB.h"`.

Comment: Ok, i got a SIGARBT signal, and my app crashed at the 2nd line there. It's the error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: Can you explain the view hierarchy again? Is `viewA` the parent of `viewC` and `viewB`? And you are trying to send a message from `viewC` to `viewB`?

Comment: I have updated the answer suggesting some changes to the approach. Take a look.

Comment: This final method worked. Thanks for all your help (everyone).

Answer (score 2):

so your code is fine.  only issue is that viewC does not have a pointer to viewA. or at least, it does not have a pointer to an instance of viewA that actually lives in memory.

you allocated and instanciate an instance of ViewA.  which then instanciates an instance of both ViewB and ViewC.  however, the pointer that viewC has to viewA doesnt go anywhere.

so you can do a few different things.  you can either make the method on viewA a class method instead of an instance method.  (you do this by putting a + in front of the method declaration instead of a -) or you can pass viewC a pointer to viewA.

for example, give the variable "viewA" inside of viewC a setter. and have viewA set "self" as the value for this.  that way when viewC calls to that pointer, it will be referencing back to valid instance of ViewA.

when you write

"ViewA *viewA;"

that creates a pointer or type ViewA. btu that pointer doesnt point anywhere.

if you throw a breakpoint in your code and you check out viewA in the debugger you will see that its 0x0.  (meaning it doesnt exists in memory)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, Declare your **methodToPass** as static

//ViewB.h

```
+(void)methodToPass;
```

//ViewB.m

```
+(void)methodToPass  
{  
// Your code  
}
```

Now in your **ViewC.m** access the method as

```
[ViewB methodToPass];
```

You don't have to create object for the view. You can directly access the method by class name. Hope this helps.